# Google map region boundary have mutiple line

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have implemented google map boundary in our site [www.kozaza.com](http://www.kozaza.com).Yesterday we noticed that multiple lines showing on region boundary.Can you help me to resolve this issue. I believe this is something related with google map code, because we haven't touched our code for last 1 month.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with 'we noticed that multiple lines showing on region boundary'? Can you add screenshots?

Comment: After just a brief look it seems that your region borders don't match the region borders drawn on a map. If you could make them more accurate it would help. Alternatively you could try to remove region borders from map tiles, but I don't think they are layers so it would be impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like google updated their map tiles. You should be able to [style the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) to remove the existing boundaries if you can't find data for borders that matches them.

Looks like they don't match the [boundaries in the Natural Earth data set](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=Korea,%20South) either: